# Measure if bottle level is empty

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, sensor, hobbyist

Consider an upside bottle with liquid (water) oozing out from pinhole on head. I need to detect if water falls below a certain level.
I searched and saw there are multiple sensors already available for this but my constraints are that I want to externally place the detection circuit and make it as cheap as possible, in short, no need to give it microcontroller brain.

I was thinking to use Red LED to emit and a photodiode/phototransistor to detect.
When water will be filled the light won't reach (my assumption, please correct if this faulty and my first beginning step is only wrong) and when water falls it will be visible to photodiode and it will trigger an alarm immediately.

Thanks community.

Comment: what's a head? `pinhole on head`

Comment: how does air get into the bottle?

Comment: If you are going to use light of some wavelength range, perhaps a cheaper approach to consider (I do NOT have an answer, only a thought) is that if you press the LED source flush with the bottle surface there will be differing reflections back (you'll need a detector, too) if water is present on the other side of the glass, or not. If you find an optimal way to arrange the LED and detector against the glass and if you choose a wavelength that optimizes the difference you may be able to design something cheap and without an MCU. Were it me, I'd see study and experimentation ahead.

Comment: Assume a pinhole on the bottle cap (head). Take a bottle fill with water and do hole in cap. Now turn bottle up down that's how air goes inside.

Comment: @ReddiSuresh so that is two holes from your comment, is one for liquid and one for air? How do you control which is which?

Comment: Umm @solar Mike, let's say we have some holes in bottle bottom where air can get in (we can remove this discussion on air getting inside, as it's off trend here)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with using light is that water is generally clear and the light from a red LED will go right through it. You could possibly detect the small difference in the light level caused by refraction rather than a 'light/no light' state but that gets to be more complicated.
An alternative is to use an LED with a near-infrared wavelength of 1450 nm which gets absorbed by water. There are commercial devices that use this method.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water

Comment: So you mean to say that an LED emitting light with such a wavelength that it gets absorbed so anyhow it won't be visible on other side, and when level goes down it will be visible? Also, should I also focus on material of bottle?

Comment: Yes, at that wavelength it would be as if the water was black. You would also need to make sure the bottle did not block this wavelength.

Comment: Or you could float a block of something in the water that did block visible light.

Answer (score 0):

How about a load cell (weight sensor) holding the bottle up? Measure the weight of a nearly empty bottle. Once the weight of your dripping bottle drops below that, it's almost empty.

Comment: So, I'll need to first measure it and then set it when value goes below certain threshold, won't it be much tiresome everytime to go through process? Say i have different bottle  of different weight and all. If my original electronic circuit can work then we can fit it and ready to go. (Keeping in view that it will be adjusted easily to diameter of bottle)

Comment: @ReddiSuresh If you're going to keep changing the size and weight of the bottle, then whatever system you use is going to need adjusting and recalibrating each time.

Comment: No, not necessary, the content inside if same, and my setup if can fit varying diameter from a min to max range of operation, then it can be used